# AND(&&) condition in EC2 command line tools --filter option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using EC2 command line tools like this

```
ec2-describe-tags --filter "resource-type=instance"  --filter "value=value1" --filter "key=key1" --filter "value=value2" --filter "key=key2"
```

I want to know how to put this filters in AND(&&) . I want that output should only contain results that satisfies all the filters.

Answer (score 5):

Using the newer [`aws ec2`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) API, the following filters have && relation between them:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=instance" "Name=value,Values=value1" "Name=key,Values=key1" "Name=value,Values=value2" "Name=key,Values=key2"
```

Comment: At first I thought this didn't work, but that was because I'd also duplicated the `--filters` option with each. As Uri shows, it's just a space separated list of filters

Comment: How to do a search based on || (or) relation in filters ?

Comment: @singh ofr || (or) relation use the `--filter` flag multiple times like in the user's question.